# Исправить код (Парсер строки)

Tags: c++, linux

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int arc, const char *argv[])
{

    while (true)
    {
        char buf[1024];
        char command[100];
        char path[100];

        std::cout << "Enter command and path: ";
        std::cin.getline(buf, 100);

        int i, j;

        for (i = 0; (buf[i] != ' ') && (buf[i] != '\n'); command[i] = buf[i], i++);

        if ((buf[i] == ' ') && (buf[i + 1] != '\n'))
        {
            i += 1;
            for (j = 0; (buf[i] != ' ') && (buf[i] != '\n'); path[j] = buf[i], j++, i++);
        }

        std::cout << "command = " << command << " path = " << path << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

исправить код ... тут не корректно работает 
Мне нужно чтобы я каждый раз печатал команду и путь и программа разделил команду от пути в разные массивы
Но здесь если команда короче предыдущей команды то он не презеписывыается в массиве ...

Comment: `\0` не записываешь.

Comment: Странно, вроде Си++, а код совершенно не использует его возможностей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После строки

```
for (i = 0; (buf[i] != ' ') && (buf[i] != '\n'); command[i] = buf[i], i++);
```

Добавьте строчку

```
command[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло